# Get Data from Controller to Modal View Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, model, controller

I am having a hard time to figure out on how to delete the rows from the table using Bootsrap modal.

This is my **Model** function:

```
function view_product(){

    $query = $this->db->get('product_tbl');
    return $query;
}
```

this this my **Controller**:

```
    public function list() {

        $page = 'list';
        
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }


        $data['title'] = "Delete Product";
        $data['fetch_data'] = $this->Product_model->view_product();

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/modal'); // MODAL
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

And this is my **View**, wherein the 'remove' button is my problem:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="table-light">
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Product</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">QR Code</th>
            <th colspan="2" scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id='myTable'>

        <?php
            if($fetch_data->num_rows() > 0){

                foreach($fetch_data->result() as $data){
                    $product_id = $data->product_id;
                    $db_image = $data->image;
                    $db_product_name = $data->product_name;
                    $db_price = $data->price;
                    $db_quantity = $data->quantity;
                    $db_qr_code = $data->qr_code;

                    echo "
                        <tr>
                            <th scope='row'>$db_image</th>
                            <td>$db_product_name</td>
                            <td>$db_price</td>
                            <td>$db_quantity</td>
                            <td>$db_qr_code</td>
                            <td width='30px'><a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='edit/$product_id' role='button'>Details</a></td>
                
                            <td width='30px'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'>Remove</button></td>
                        </tr>

                        ";
                }
            }
        ?>
```

The question is how am i going to GET the data from the DB to delete/remove a particular row from the table using Bootstrap modal? Is there any code that I need to add in the Model? or in Controller?

Thank u! Any answer would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to delete data from your view to be persisted in the database is create a simple function in your controller that would delete a product based on this ID (or whatever unique variable you want to use) calling a function from you model.

Then in your view, you can call this delete function through javascript using AJAX.

Please remember to check for authorization in your controller.

What you'd be doing here is create an API, and if you want your code to be compliant with RESTful architecture, you'd want to make a `DELETE` call from AJAX instead of a `GET`.